# Safari - Remove text space in anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I've checked my site on Firefox, Chrome and IE, and it is working well. But when I use Safari, I am getting this problem:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
.primary-define #topbar #welcome {
    float: right;
    font-size: 0;
    min-width: 92px;
}
```

When I use "Web Inspector" in Safari, I know it is affected by text inside and outside the anchor tag:

```
<div id="welcome">
    Welcome visitor you can
    <a href="#">login</a> 
    or 
    <a href="#">create an account</a>
</div>
```

Hope anyone can help me fix this problem. I tried many ways but nothing changed.

Thank in advance.

Comment: add a fiddle or something. And give full header code.

Comment: @SSS You could check my site here: http://nipponten.com/

Answer (score 0):

`font-size:0` do not kill white space bug in Safari.

`letter-spacing` is required to fix this bug in Safari. Give `letter-spacing:-.5em;`.